# Passing a variable inside a LINQ.js query

Tags: javascript, json, linq.js

I am trying to query my JSON data which is stored in data.json file.
I successfully got desired result when i give static value inside the linq query but when i am passing a variable after user chooses a value from drop down menu, the linq query is not taking its dynamic value. here is my working  code for static value.

```
$("#community").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'json/data.json',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(searchres) {
            //console.log(searchres);   
            /////////////////////////////assigning searched results to handlebar.js
            var community = $('#community').val();
            var queryResult = Enumerable.From(searchres)
                .Where("$.kls_commId = 7 ")
                .ToArray();
            console.log(queryResult);
            //var bb = Handlebars.compile($('#beds').html());
            //  $('.mybeds').append(bb(responseBeds));
            /////////////////////////////assigning searched results to handlebar.js

        }
    });
});
```

Now i have to pass the select box value inside the where clause,
i tried, `Where("$.kls_commId = community ")` or `Where("$.kls_commId = $('#community').val() ")` but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

got the answer. i had to use .Where("$.kls_commId == " +community)

Answer (score -1):

I am the author to jinqJs

Using jinqJs you could access outside variables by doing the following:

var nm = 'Tom';

result = jinqJs()
                 .from(data1)
                 .where ('Name == ' + nm)
                 .select(predicate);